# Magento: product bulk import on cron run

Tags: magento, import, product

I have more than 2000 product, are updating on cron run. The procedure is delete the product first and then import. I am using:

`$product->delete()` for delete. But its taking long time to run whole script and getting 
`500 Internal error.` How can I optimize this one.

I really need to get out from here. I also increased my php.ini max_execution_time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather then a delete break this into three parts:

1. Delete by checking what are going to be non existent as per feed received.
2. Insert/update other products.
3. If for some reason if you still want to delete all, delete a smaller chunk of product and loop till all are deleted.

Comment: Thanks, I also thought to delete smaller chunk.